# how to start Intellij from command line in windows?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, cmd

How do I start intellij from command line in windows? for instance like we open vs code from cmd by writing `code .` from the current directory.

I added the bin folder of intellij to path and then tried writing `idea .` and intellij opened but some unusual things showing up in the cmd [picture of cmd after writing `idea .`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d7Ys.png)
and a folder gets created in the current directory with the name `. idea` and with these contents [picture of the folder with the contents inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE16n.png)

Comment: Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/opening-files-from-command-line.html and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

Find out the path of idea64.exe by right clicking on the icon.

e.g. in my case it was: c:\Program files\choco\intellij-idea-ue\bin\idea64.exe

Then do this on **Windows Powershell**: start "c:\Program files\choco\intellij-idea-ue\bin\idea64.exe"

Comment: I had the same issue and this is a great idea. Don't know why I didn't think about it. For those wondering, if you update to the latest version (say 2023.3.3) the `idea64.exe` isn't in the bin folder as described in the docs, it's actually in 2023.1.1 so right clicking to get shortcut properties is best idea